# Change notification settings for Android App

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, android-app

Minor gripe, but... can we please be allowed to change the notification settings on the Android app?

I personally don't need my phone to vibrate and ring. And I don't want the sound to be the default; I want customization!

Comment: So this comment makes your phone vibrate and ring? ...ha...haha..muwahahaha

Comment: @Bart -_- yes... yes it does... though I thought ahead and just put it on vibrate to alleviate this :)

Comment: No android here, but in my iPhone those options are "external", via the phone settings for each app. So in android each app can decide those things all by itself?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It is external (Settings app) for the default settings, when you want to alter specific app settings it is within the app itself that it takes place.

Comment: @TronicZomB hmm... this makes me not want android that much. It's like a website that will turn my volume on or off, or increase the volume. Oh well, enough off topic rant. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Some roms allow you to change it per app, from the outside but yeah, it should really be built into the OS.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett well, it is in iOS. :-)

Comment: Yeah, this is planned. I'd also like some "depending on daytime" setting, i.e. if you sleep with your WiFi-enabled phone next to you, you can tell the app not to vibrate/make noise between 10pm and 8am or something like that.

Comment: @balpha that would be a rather nice added aspect to the feature.

Comment: @balpha: I have [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) for that. (When home: connect Wi-Fi and lower all volumes). However, having it on any specific app would be very nice too :D

Comment: I have had to disable notifications as this is so annoying! hopefully when it gets fixed I will remember to re-enable them again

Comment: Most (all that I've seen?) Android apps have the notification settings within the application; I found this as far as the developer guidelines:

`Make notifications optional

Users should always be in control of notifications. Allow the user to disable your apps notifications or change their alert properties, such as alert sound and whether to use vibration, by adding a notification settings item to your application settings.` http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implemented as of version 0.1.66 coming out tonight!

I'd still like to implement something along the lines of what [balpha mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193361/change-notification-settings-for-android-app#comment605867_193361) too, but that's not part of the requirements to finish this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to me.

[image]

Edit: The remaining part of this as explained above is [now implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209079/allow-me-to-automatically-silence-notifications-during-night-time)

Comment: +1 I just went out of my way to update instead of waiting for Play Store auto update for this

Comment: @StevenV I am so happy I added it :) Now if I could just get it to automatically silence notifications between 1 AM and noon...

Answer (score 9):

I concur that the notifications can be super-annoying and not having control over them is a design flaw.

As mentioned in the comments, it's possible to disable notifications specifically for an app. Here's how to do it for most devices I've seen, with recent enough Android version:

1. Open App Info, e.g. Settings -> Application manager -> Downloaded -> Stack Exchange
2. Uncheck "Show notifications"

   [image: App Info / Show notifications]

Comment: Thanks, reminding me of this really helped me, but (as @Peter commented above) the app should really allow customizing of the notifications natively (for example I'd like the notification, but no vibration/ringtone for it).