# Allow me to automatically silence notifications during night time

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, android-app

The android app now has the ability to remove vibration and noises from push notifications but to get what I want out of it I still have to manually disable those at night then re-enable them when I wake up.

The app should automatically squash noise and vibration from those notifications during a time span that I can edit.

Comment: YOU CAN'T SILENCE ME NOW!!!

Comment: Still trying to catch up to iOS, I see...

Comment: This, is not, a test. Or is it?

Comment: Come on, you can get this feature working correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now you can!

Using the quiet hours button at the bottom of the app's settings (found using the overflow menu) you can now enable this feature and modify the time when it starts and ends every day.

[image]

Comment: Rep whore! ;) I love this, though!

Comment: Sometimes I talk to myself.

Comment: That's the best way to be sure you are talking to someone on your intellectual level ;)

Comment: @Andrew That never works for me..

Comment: @James strangely, me either...

Comment: @Doorknob I know, Andrew is right. Wow, how is it that we agree on everything? :D

Comment: You guys are missing the headline, here. Asked: 23:44:33. Answered: 23:44:33. _Kasra develops software infinitely quickly!_

Comment: @Pops Impossible. Fraction of a second later. `E=MC^2` is intact. ;)

Comment: [#NewWayOfDevsForShineyRep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210943/cant-log-in-on-meta-stackoverflow-com#comment677173_210943)