# Can't log in on meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, login

I'm logging this for you, since you clearly can't!

Working on it... it is something to do with MVC 5. Normal service will be resumed shortly.

Comment: No repo here, but I guess that's because I'm already logged in. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 indeed, only impacts the actual authenticate step

Comment: This is only in mso or all metas?

Comment: @Braiam MSO - the "revert! revert!" build has almost finished...

Comment: Revert faster!!!!!

Comment: Wow! Self bug report, self solution, and self status-completed! #NewWayOfDevsForShineyRep

Comment: Bug selfie - guess that's a new one!

Comment: Did someone try to refactor the `HandleSuccess` method?

Comment: @Mad - we can't `HandleSuccess`. You know this.

Comment: @Mad only Jon Skeet can really do that, but unfortunately he's not working for Stack Exchange... ;-)