# 404 when trying to login on per-site metas

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, per-site-meta

### How to reproduce:

1. Wander aimlessly into some meta site (either, logged on some other site or not logged at all)
2. Try to upvote/downvote/do something that requires you to be logged in (this will trigger the login or create an account)
3. Click any login option
4. ...
5. ....

### What happens?

You get a [404 not found error](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate?returnurl=/questions/2560/titles-that-contain-tags).

### What this silly user thinks should happen?

Either, allow me to login or do not show me the box to login in the first place.

### Impact?

All per-site metas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't log in on meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210943/cant-log-in-on-meta-stackoverflow-com)

Comment: @MadScientist - no, not a dupe.

Comment: @Oded Meta, per-site meta, all the same to me ;-). Oh well, next time I'll try to read the question properly before closing

Comment: @MadScientist - details, details. It's not like we are programmers who deal with minute details all the time.

Comment: Solution: don't wander aimlessly in per meta sites! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm a natural born wanderer!

Comment: Could not reproduce

Comment: Reproduced/duplicate: [Error 404: Aviation meta sign up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214989)

Comment: @Laura when was it fixed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure; probably when we redesigned the signup and login pages. Someone flagged saying that this was no longer a problem, and I poked around for a bit and couldn't repo, so I'm calling it done. I trust that someone will post again if there's an edge case I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they should be substituted with this:

[image]

Comment: That needs to end up on [music.se]...

Comment: Johnny what happened to your tree??

Comment: Some douche thought it was offensive and cut it down.  If nature offends you, you have issues.

Comment: @JohnnyBones didn't see your reply! Well, it had a pretty unique shape... but we're still in a good stand, [Facebook ban accounts using naked **dolls** as their profile pictures](http://rossdawsonblog.com/weblog/archives/2010/07/breaking_facebo.html)! ;-(