# Error 404: Aviation meta sign up

Tags: discussion, support, beta-sites, specific-site

I was clicking on signing up with Google and got this url which leads to a 404 error. I was doing the following steps:

1) [We need to ask more questions!](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/we-need-to-ask-more-questions)

2) Click on upvote.

3) Click on sign-up with the google account.

https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate?returnurl=%2Fquestions%2F143%2Fwe-need-to-ask-more-questions

The interesting thing is that if I click on "Sign up" at the top on the [main site](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com), it works fine.

Comment: Discussion about this question: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1716838#1716838